# M1 MacBook Pro - Internal Volume after deletion not more visible

Tags: hdd

I wanted to make a plain reinstall of Mac OS Venture with a USB stick on my M1. After booting I went into the disk util and erase the MacintoshHD Volume. But now I can not add a new startup volume and also the installation program in recovery mode doesn't detect an internal HD. Can Someone please help ? Maybe with diskutil or other command line Tools?

Thank you all in advance !
[image]

Comment: You've deleted most of the internal disk structure, including Recovery. Why did you do that?  There is almost never a need to mess with this stuff. Either take it to an Apple Store, or if you have another Mac, you can use Apple's Configurator app to restore it.